# Передача значения объекта из Java в с++

Tags: java, c++

Читаю книгу про компиляторы(книга дракона), разбираюсь как лексические и синтаксические анализаторы программируются. В конце книги есть пример написанный на языке java. Я программирую на с++ и поэтому пример переделал под этот язык. Но столкнулся с одной проблемой.
Имеется такой класс:

```
public class Word extends Token {
public String lexeme = "";
public Word(String s, int tag)
{
    super(tag);
    lexeme = s;
}
public String ToString()
{
    return lexeme;
}
public static final Word 
    and = new Word("&&", Tag.AND),
    or = new Word("||", Tag.OR),
    eq = new Word("==", Tag.EQ),
    ne = new Word("!=", Tag.NE),
    le = new Word("<=", Tag.LE),
    ge = new Word(">=", Tag.GE),
    minus = new Word("minus", Tag.MINUS),
    True = new Word("true", Tag.TRUE),
    False = new Word("false", Tag.FALSE),
    temp = new Word("t", Tag.TEMP);
}
```

Объект этого класса записывается в хеш таблицу:

```
Hashtable words = new Hashtable();
String s = b.toString();
.....
Word w = (Word)words.get(s);
words.put(w.lexeme, w);
```

В предпоследней строке приводится к типу Word результат, как можно такое в с++ реализовать. И самый главный вопрос в последней строке в качестве ключа используется объект. Как сделать аналогично на с++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В предпоследней строке приводится к типу Word результат, как можно такое в с++ реализовать.

Вам не нужно делать никаких преобразований - создайте map, который будет хранить объекты типа `Word`. В Java тип `Object` является суперклассом для всех классов, то есть любой тип - его наследник. Поэтому можно делать подобные преобразования - `(Word)words.get(s)`.

> И самый главный вопрос в последней строке в качестве ключа
>   используется объект.

В качестве ключа используется строка. Посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put-K-V-).

P.S. В классе `Lexer` Вам придется хранить не только инстансы класса Word, но и его наследников. Подумайте, какой тип использовать в map'е, чтобы его впоследствии можно было кастовать к наследникам (в `std::map<Key, Word>` объект типа `Type` Вы уже не вставите).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @helldrg, рад помочь!